Redirect Login Based on User Role
I'm currently using the following code to add a login form to a page.  How can I redirect users after they have logged in based on a custom user role.
function my_login_form() {

    $args = array(
      'echo'            => true,
      'redirect'        => get_permalink(get_the_ID()),
      'remember'        => true,
      'value_remember'  => true,
    );
  
    return wp_login_form($args);
  
}

add_shortcode('my_login', 'my_login_form');

For example, I would like my "test_user_role" to redirect to the admin page "/wp-admin/users.php".
I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.
function dashboard_redirect($url) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if (in_array('test_user_role', (array) $user->roles)) {
        $url = admin_url('users.php');
    }else{
        $url = admin_url('index.php');
    }

    return $url;
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'dashboard_redirect');   

Edit:
It seems that when using the login_redirect action the user role isn't available.  I tried adding a priority to the filter but that didn't work.

can you ellaborate more on what you mean by redirect arg and by custom user roles? Keep in mind that until the user has logged in you have no idea who they are or which role they have, modifying the redirect parameter inside the shortcode requires some kind of prescience of the future, or asking the user before they go to a page that has this shortcode who they intend to log in as. It would be much easier to instead write a hook that runs once a user has logged in to redirect them to your preferred location

Right, that makes sense.  I'll rewrite my question.

function dashboard_redirect($url, $request, $user) {
   
    if (in_array('test_user_role', (array) $user->roles)) {
        $url = admin_url('users.php');
    }else{
        $url = admin_url('index.php');
    }

    return $url;
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'dashboard_redirect', 10, 3);  

The user can be passed into your function with a little more argument specificity.

Oh man, that was simple!  Thanks!
